# Removing all the new line character (\n) in all the items in a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list

```
my_list=[['N/A - Header', 'N/A - Header', 'N/A - Header', 'On this, Login to site. \nVerify the following email ids option is available:\nlol text\nClick on the "Help text" option.']

I want to replace "\n" to " "
```

my desired output should be,

```
  my_list=[['N/A - Header', 'N/A - Header', 'N/A - Header', 'On this, Login to site.  Verify the following email ids option is available: lol text Click on the "Help text" option.']
```

want to replace for all the items in the list

Comment: is it always the last element in the list that you want to remove the new lines from?

Comment: Your list starts with `[[` and ends with `]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
p = [x.replace('\n', ' ') for y in my_list for x in y]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_wihout_newlines = [x.replace(r'\n', ' ') for x in my_list]
```